# MySQL REGEXP acting with case sensitivity without BINARY mode?

Tags: mysql, rlike

I'm quite confused. I have a source string in the database; some HTML:

```
"body": "<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><div dir=\"auto\">Nope no attachment</div><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"gmail_attr\">
```

Here's the SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column_details REGEXP '(nope.no).attach';
```

When I select this with REGEXP of '(nope.no).attach' it fails to match. When I uppercase the Nope, it matches. When I LCASE(column_details) and go back to lower-case nope, it matches. What's going on here? My understanding is REGEXP is case insensitive, and as far as I know I'm not enforcing binary mode... or is it binary by default? If so, how do I make it case insensitive and disable binary mode matching?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of column_details?  that's going to determine the case sensitivity, just like if the value was 'N' and you did column_details='n'

Comment: What is the collation of `column_details`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that REGEXP is case-insensitive. It depends on the collation of the column. REGEXP can be case-sensitive or insensitive.

```
mysql> set @h = '<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><div dir=\"auto\">Nope no attachment</div><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"gmail_attr\">';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @h regexp '(nope.no).attach';
+------------------------------+
| @h regexp '(nope.no).attach' |
+------------------------------+
|                            1 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @h collate utf8mb4_bin regexp '(nope.no).attach';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| @h collate utf8mb4_bin regexp '(nope.no).attach' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd check the collation of your column:

```
SELECT COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_details';
```

Comment: note that a *blob or varbinary type will have a null collation, and match case-sensitively.

Comment: Ahh - it's a JSON object, so that would explain it. And you were correct! Collating to utf8mb4_unicode_ci fixed it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: BTW is there any way to have the JSON object default to utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation? My guess is defining the collation in the SELECT will slow things down quite a bit?

Comment: Regexp can't use an index anyway. In MySQL 8.0 you can define an index on the expression, but only for a fixed pattern. I assume you want something that can work with any other pattern, but that's not possible to optimize.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a ton @BillKarwin. Your answers were solid and very helpful!